# How to make form non required?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, field, required

I have one issue, to make custom [field non-required field](https://grandchinaatl.com/checkout/). I use Magee Restaurant plugin for Wordpress, and when try to checkout, there is one field named "Table Number". For default that field is required. How to make non-required? [image]

Label is named:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required" id="mgrt_table_num_dine_field" data-priority=""><label for="mgrt_table_num_dine" class="">Table Number <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input type="text" class="input-text " name="mgrt_table_num_dine" id="mgrt_table_num_dine" placeholder="Insert your table number." value=""></p>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thing that plugin is using `woocommerce_form_field` function. In that case we can use it's filter. This should do it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_args', 'magee_table_number_field_args', 10, 3 );
function magee_table_number_field_args( $args, $key, $value ){
    if ( $key == 'mgrt_table_num_dine' ) {
        $args['required'] = false;
    }
    return $args;
}
```